# C#. Webbrowser. Как ограничить список URL,по которым можно переходить внутри элементы WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста как ограничить список URL,по которым можно переходить внутри элементы WebBrowser?

Например WebBrowser будет загружать только site.com. На нём есть ссылки на другие сайты например site2.com
Нужно как-то запретить из открытие,чтобы можно было переходить только по ссылкам содержащим site.com

Это возможно? Спасибо заранее!!

Answer (score 2):

Событие [`Navigating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating(v=vs.110).aspx) позволяет посмотреть url, на который собирается переходить браузер и отменить переход.